# Get values of radio selected values of entire row to next file

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have displayed the values from mysql table along with radio buttons with different values. On submit button it should redirect to next page and display the selected values. My code on first file is as follows :

```
$query1 = "select * from booking";
$result1 = $connection->query($query1);
echo "<form method='post' action='edit.php'>";
echo "<center>";
echo "<table border='1'>";
$count = 0;
while($row = $result1->fetch_row())
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width=".'10'.">";
    $count = $count + 1;
    #$sr=$sr+1;
    echo "<input type='radio' name='select' value='".$count."' />";
    #$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result1);
    #echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width=".'10'.">";
    $rooms = $row[0];
    $srrooms = $rooms;
    echo "<input type='text' name='srrooms' value='".$srrooms."'     hidden='hidden'>";
    #echo $srrooms;
    echo $rooms;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td width=".'10'.">";
    $no_roomss = $row[1];
    $nosrrooms = $no_roomss;
    echo "<input type='text' name='nosrrooms' value='".$nosrrooms."' hidden='hidden'>";
    echo $no_roomss;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td width=".'10'.">";
    $no_dayss = $row[2];
    $nodays = $no_dayss;
    echo "<input type='text' name='nodays' value='".$nodays."' hidden='hidden'>";
    echo $no_dayss;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td width=".'10'.">";
    $name = $row[3];
    echo $name;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    #$count++;
}
echo "<input name='count' type='hidden' id='count'>"; // hidden input where     counter value will be stored
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submitRooms' />";
echo "</center>";
echo "</form>";
```

The javascript code is :
                 
    
    $(function(){
        $('input[name="select"]').change(function(){
            $('#count').val($("input[name='select']:checked").val());
        });
    });

edit.php code is :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitRooms'])){
    @$count = $_POST['count'];
    @$srrooms=$_POST['srrooms'.$count];
    @$nosrrooms=$_POST['nosrrooms'.$count];
    @$nodays=$_POST['nodays'.$count];
    echo 'Selected values are: '. $srrooms . $nosrrooms . $nodays;
}
?>
```

Comment: One option, hit submit, store the values from the form into a session variable and loop through the session on the next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use counter for submitting the values of the selected radiobutton's row as:

```
<?php 
$query1 = "select * from booking";
$result1 = $connection->query($query1);
echo "<form method='post' action='edit.php'>";
echo "<center>";
echo "<table border='1'>";

$count = 0; // counter variable
while($row = $result1->fetch_row())
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width=".'10'.">";

    echo "<input type='radio' name='select' value='".$count."' />";
    echo "<td width=".'10'.">";
    $rooms = $row[0];
    $srrooms = $rooms;

    echo "<input type='hidden' name='srrooms".$count."' value='".$srrooms."' >"; // add counter value to every name of the input fields
    echo $rooms;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td width=".'10'.">";
    $no_roomss = $row[1];
    $nosrrooms = $no_roomss;
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='nosrrooms".$count."' value='".$nosrrooms."'>";
    echo $no_roomss;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td width=".'10'.">";
    $no_dayss = $row[2];
    $nodays = $no_dayss;
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='nodays".$count."' value='".$nodays."' >";
    echo $no_dayss;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td width=".'10'.">";
    $name = $row[3];
    echo $name;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $count++;
}
echo "<input name='count' type='hidden' id='count'>"; // hidden input where counter value will be stored
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submitRooms' />";
echo "</center>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

and then use jquery for saving the active radiobuttons count in the hidden count input field [after the above php code]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
    $('input[name="select"]').change(function(){
        $('#count').val($("input[name='select']:checked").val());
    });
});
</script>
```

then on your edit.php fetch the posted data as:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitRooms'])){
    @$count = $_POST['count'];
    @$srrooms = $_POST['srrooms'.$count];
    @$nosrrooms = $_POST['nosrrooms'.$count];
    @$nodays = $_POST['nodays'.$count];
    echo 'Selected values are: '. $srrooms . $nosrrooms . $nodays;
}
?>
```

You didn't have added the whole form code so please add the above mentioned form code and the reason why your code is not working is that you haven't added the count with the input field names. And their is no use of fetching the posted data with count in the edit.php till you don't have the input fields named with the $count variable

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='srrooms".$count."' value='".$srrooms."' >";
```

Comment: Thank you for such prompt response. I have copied the same code but on edit.php, I am getting errors as : 'Notice: Undefined index: srrooms1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Hotel\edit.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: nosrrooms1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Hotel\edit.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: nodays1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Hotel\edit.php on line 6
Selected values are:'

Comment: or if you going to use the edit.php independently you can use @ sign before your statement..check the code again I have added it

Comment: now the errors are gone but it showing nothing. It is showing : Selected values are:

Comment: you submitted the form by selecting the radio button..right?

Comment: Yes, submitted form by selecting the radio button.

Comment: this code worked fine on my end...did you changed the whole php code of form?

Comment: and please check on your page frontend if there is any element named 'nosrrooms1' or 'nodays1' if not found any element then check if you have added the $count variable in the code...

Comment: I have not changed the php code of form. Also there are no elements named as 'nosrrooms1' or 'nodays1'. $count variable is also used as in your provided code in edit.php

Comment: can you show me your code? just update your question with that

Comment: so please copy the whole code of the form then check

Comment: it won't work till you don't add the $count with the name of the input fields

Comment: I have copied the whole code here. Also $count is used as per your suggestions. The table got displayed on this admin.php file along with radio buttons and when we select a radio button, that particular row will get fetched to edit.php page for updation. Also, on edit.php, if I echo the $count variable,  it is showing the correct value of selected radio button. But other variable like $_POST['srrooms'.$count] are null.

Comment: Yes, I am using the exact code and updated the same in actual question.

Comment: do it like this:                         echo "<input type='hidden' name='srrooms".$count."' value='".$srrooms."' >";

Comment: Still nothing. I have updated the edit.php as follows :                                <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitRooms'])){
        @$count = $_POST['count'];
     @$srrooms=$_POST['srrooms'.$count];
     echo "<input type='hidden' name='srrooms".$count."'     value='".$srrooms."' >";
        @$nosrrooms=$_POST['nosrrooms'.$count];
        @$nodays=$_POST['nodays'.$count];
        echo 'Selected values are: '. $srrooms . $nosrrooms . $nodays;
    }
    ?>

Comment: look i'm not talking about edit.php . That file is updated fine...i'm just asking you to update the file where you are creating your form via php

Comment: and you are not updating your file with my code....please just go through whole code i've given here in answer and compare that with your code...this code is working all fine

Comment: you are correct. It was my mistake. Updated the form code as per your suggestion and it started working. Thank you so much..  :)